# Get the latitude and longitude coordinates based on a set of address values for any country

Tags: c#, maps, windows-phone, latitude-longitude

my problem is the following:

I have a text box that contains the address to be searched. Do not want to show the result on a map control that I want to get only the distance between the device and the point found.

I tried to implement the code using the HERE Maps API, but I was informed that it does not work for my problem. I found the Bing REST API but not sure how to implement what I need.

If some simple way to do using some function to calculate the two points please advise me there.

I do not know how to get search results as well as its coordinates. The API link I found is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx

Comment: Please find someone to translate your question a little better. I think I know what you are asking but it is REALLY confusing.

Comment: @AMR Sorry, I've refreshed the ask question.

Comment: are you looking for a way to calculate distance between 2 points? is that what you want?

Comment: @Mimi I've solved the problem, but I'm not finished the code. After finished I'll post here. Thank's.